# using delcaration to inherit constructors from all base classes given by variadic template arg

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-templates, using

If I derive from one or more classes I can inherit the constructors with the `using` declaration.

Example:

```
struct A
{
    A(int){}
    A(){}
};

struct B
{
    B(char){}
    B(){}
};

struct All: public A,public B
{
    using A::A;
    using B::B;
};
```

If I want do the same within a template class, where the base classes are given by a variadic template parameter, how can I use the using declaration?

Example ( The same as above, but using a template class to inherit )

```
template < typename ... P>
struct All2: public P...
{
    using P...::P...; ??? is there a syntax available to "use" the constructors from all base classes?
};
```

And the main can be something like:

```
int main()
{
    All all1(1);
    All2<A,B> all2(2);
}
```

Comment: bad idea because: what will construct the other classes that were inherited from?  If you call All's A constructor, what will initialize All's B bytes?  On top of that, what will you do if both A and B constructors take the same args?

Comment: @Abel: It is a pure hypothetical example. I need it in a different context, the question is only to get an idea which syntax we will need, fully independent of the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template < typename ... P>
struct All2: public P...
{
    using P::P...;
};
```

Comment: Wow! It needs gcc 11 to compile. My system comes with 10.3 and that did not work... Do you know if it is a fixed bug?

Comment: It does indeed fail with g++ 10.3: https://godbolt.org/z/5jz6vToq4 (but works with clang++ from version 4.0)

Comment: It fails on gcc 10.3 on my PC with the same messages as on godbolt. If it was not the same error, I will wonder about :-)